# CSS3: можно ли вкладывать друг в друга стили?

Tags: html5, css3

Можно ли вкладывать друг в друга стили (так не работает, но отображена идея, что хочется сделать):

```css
nav {
  display: none;
}

#menu_open a {
 color: green;
}

#menu_close {
  display: none;
}

#menu_close a {
  color: red;
}

#nav:target {
  display: block;
}

#nav:target + #menu {
  #menu_open {
  display: none;
} 
  #menu_close {
  display: block;
}
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">price</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">contacts</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div id="menu"> 
 <div id="menu_open">
  <a href="#nav">||</a> 
 </div>
  
 <div id="menu_close">
  <a href="#">||</a> 
 </div>
  
</div>
```

Хочется, чтобы у #display_open и #display_close одновременно изменился display: на противоположный, но для этого нужно как-то стили для каждого из блоков вложить в общую обертку #menu - так вообще можно сделать без JS?

Потуги на кодпен: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OygKwO

Comment: с таким же поведением в можете использовать: `#nav:target + #menu #menu_open {` : [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VevbYg)

Comment: То, что нужно, спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

На css без сторонних библиотек нельзя. Используйте [Less.js](http://lesscss.org/)(библиотека для работы с css). Статья с примерами на [хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/136525/).

Ну или jquery конечно:
пример:

```js
$('#menu_open_or_close').on('click', function() {
  $('#nav').toggle("slow");
});
```

```css
#nav {
  display: none;
}
#menu_open a {
  color: green;
}
#menu_close {
  display: none;
}
#menu_close a {
  color: red;
}
#nav:target {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">about</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">price</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">contacts</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div id="menu">
  <div id="menu_open_or_close">
    <a href="#">||</a> 
  </div>

</div>
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fnfuyjuo/)

Comment: Хотелось бы сделать раскрывающееся-закрывающееся меню  только на html5 и css3 и без js/jquery (с ними можно и по другому реализовать такое меню), но спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @enki css3 не поддерживает вложенные css для других элементов. Используйте less.js Для этого. это библиотека предназначенная для работы с css.

Comment: Я бы не рекомендовал Less отдельно от всей когорты препроцессоров.

Answer (score 1):

> Хочется, чтобы у #display_open и #display_close одновременно изменился display: на противоположный, но для этого нужно как-то стили для каждого из блоков вложить в общую обертку #menu - так вообще можно сделать без JS?

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/449151/178988

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендую использовать Sass, за счет миксинов я его полюбил больше чем less

Comment: Он не это хочет...